# Multi-Domain routing

Tags: routing, multi-domain

We are launching 2 different sites, using the same craft installation on multiple domains.

a.com and b.com

a.com points to the main craft install

b.com should point to a subpage/single in this same craft install.
(So basically could be reached via a.com/subpage

What is the best craft internal way of doing this?

I know there is mod proxy..but we wanna handle it internally. So basically different "start" points for different domains or subdomains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple redirect is not what you're after, I assume? So a user loading b.com doesn't know that the same content is also available on a.com/sub?

Comment: Exactly. The domain should be clean. 
In the end what im after is like having a another "single" acting as a homepage but triggered by specific domains only.

Answer (score 5):

To do this, copy index.php and .htaccess from a.com’s webroot into b.com’s, and make sure the `$craftPath` variable is correct.

Then, around where `$craftPath` is getting defined, override `$_GET['p']` to make Craft think that the URI actually started with `subpath`:

```php
$craftPath = '../craft';

$_GET['p'] = 'subpath/' . (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '');

// ...
```

Now when you go to b.com/*, it will be the same as going to a.com/subpath/*.

If you want traffic going to b.com to stay on b.com, you will also need to make sure `a.com/subpath` is replaced with `b.com` in any Craft-generated URLs:

```
{{ url('foo')|replace('a.com/subpath', 'b.com') }}
```

That will also affect links on a.com, though. If you still want traffic on a.com/subpath to remain on a.com, then it’s slightly more complicated. In your craft/config/general.php file, add a custom `domain` config setting that varies depending on the requested domain:

```php
return array(
    '*' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    'a.com' => array(
        // ...
        'domain' => 'a',
    ),
    'b.com' => array(
        // ...
        'domain' => 'b',
    ),
);
```

Then in your templates, only run that `str_replace` filter when the domain is `b`:

```
{% set url = url('foo') %}
{{ craft.config.domain == 'b' ? url|replace('a.com/subpath', 'b.com') : url }}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - invaluable. But I only seem able to get this to work by prepending the `subpath/` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, rather than `$_GET['p']`: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10246/3686