# Multi-domain routing not working

Tags: routing, multi-domain

I've followed [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9170/3686) for running a Craft install based on two domain names. I thought it was working but either I was wrong, or something's changed, because it's not now.

I have a.com (where the Craft install is) and b.com. In b.com's `index.php` I have this:

```
$craftPath = '../craft';

$_GET['p'] = 'subpath/' . (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '');
```

So that if I go to `b.com/directory` it loads a page as if it was `a.com/subpath/directory`.

Except it's not - it's as if it's trying to load `a.com/directory`.

If I put this in b.com's `index.php` (after the above):

```
var_dump($_GET['p']);
exit();
```

Then I see "subpath/directory", as expected. But if in my base layout template I put this:

```
{{ craft.request.getQueryString() }}
```

Then it shows "p=directory". So it seems like "subpath/" is going missing somewhere? I'm stumped.

**UPDATE:**

If I request `b.com/index.php?p=directory` then I get the page I expect (ie, `/subpath/directory`).

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer, but I don't know if it's going to cause me any problems or not. Looking at the debug output in the JS Console I noticed that although
`$_GET['p']` was set correctly to `subpath/directory`,
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` was only set to `/directory` and
`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` was only set to `p=directory`. Maybe Craft or Yii uses the `REQUEST_URI` rather than `$_GET['p']` at some crucial stage?

So I've replaced the `$_GET['p']...` line in my `b.com/index.php` with this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'subpath/' . (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '');
```

That seems to fix things. Any reason this might be bad and wrong?

**UPDATE:** Looking back at my code now, it seems that both lines were required, to cover all occasions. So I now have this in `b.com/index.php`:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'subpath/' . (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '');

$_GET['p'] = 'subpath/' . (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '');
```

Comment: Hi this is exactly what I need to do for a site I am building. Did you experience any problems doing it this way or did it work out Ok for you? Cheers

Comment: I just looked back at my code and it looks like it still works - I've updated my answer with the latest version.